# Why does my React Website Take 43 seconds to Load?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, performance, babeljs

I'm not sure why my react website is taking so long to load. It takes 43 seconds

All I have is in index.jsx

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React from "react";
import { HashRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/Home";
ReactDOM.render(
  <HashRouter>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    </div>
  </HashRouter>,
  document.getElementById("main")
);
```

Home.jsx: imports react and renders hi

webpack.config.js : https://pastebin.com/raw/zdUws0R8

package.json : https://pastebin.com/raw/VR6pSP44

index.html : https://pastebin.com/raw/9AVNBpTN

Answer (score 0):

I checked your website and it seems to be working fine to me for now; 
For more details, I have added a:
[Website Request screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8BWE.png)

You might want to have a look at your SSL certificate though.
 All the best!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reinstall your project via :

```
npx create-react-app YourProject
```

and use

> BrowserRouter

instead of

> HashRouter

in **'react-router-dom'**
then start the development server after creating the components or editing it via

```
npm start
```

Comment: An explanation regarding why/how that would resolve the problem is probably in order; I can't think of any reason this would provide a meaningful load time performance boost.